# connection minecraft with website using node.js or html

Tags: html, node.js, minecraft

i wanna type something like  www.myserverip.com/reward/(any nickname)
and the player who type his nickname in (any nickname) got in minecraft 1 diamonds someone has idea about that?

editing my website

but i dont know, How to do url to minecraft

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your server, like how is your game server is running, is it on a VM or hosted by a hosting provider etc

Comment: my server is on vm

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with modded versions of Minecraft Servers, but I do know a way to interact with Minecraft Servers using nodejs.

The [ScriptServer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptserver) package allows you to run a Minecraft server and read the chat, as well as execute commands.

Setup is relatively easy, just remember to set these properties in your `server.properties` file:

```
enable-rcon=true
rcon.port=12345
rcon.password=password
```

Example code:

```
const ScriptServer = require('scriptserver');

const server = new ScriptServer({
  core: {
    jar: 'minecraft_server.jar', //the jarfile of the server
    args: ['-Xmx2G'], //arguments for RAM usage, etc.
    rcon: {
      port: '12345',
      password: 'password'
    }
  }
});
server.start();
```

---

Next, you would need to set up a website/API, using something like [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("reward/*",(req,res)=>{
  giveReward(req);
  res.send();
});

app.listen(/* Some port number here */)
```

The function `giveReward` takes the request and attempts to give the player a diamond. The code might look something like this:

```
function giveReward(request){
  //assuming that the path looks like "/reward/username"
  const username = request.path.split("/")[2];
  server.send(`give ${username} diamond`);
}
```

You may need to tweak the code to fit your exact problem, but this should help you get an idea of how to do things.